# Can a country have good or bad fate? What decides it?

Tags: karma

We know that persons or individual entities have fate, but some countries and their citizens
like US, UK, Russia etc enjoy their lives and some countries like Afganisthan, Iraq etc are facing bad fate.

What decides a country to be having good fate or bad fate?

Comment: In a way the country's fate is only as good as the fate of individuals who live in it, it's important to remember that countries are just logical partitions created in the civilized world by human beings. Fate only applies to anything that has life and does not apply to a thing

Comment: Are you asking wrt astrology?